# How to detect #import of a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

We'd like to have some conditional compiles around code based on whether an `#import` was performed for a particular DLL. If there were a symbol that was created with `#define` it could be easily tested, but we haven't found any.

A.h:

```
#ifdef ... // what goes here?
    // do something with testing.dll
#else
    // do some alternate stuff
#endif
```

X.cpp:

```
#import "testing.dll"
#include "A.h"
```

Y.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

Comment: Notice that `#import` is not standard C++

Comment: Just declare the oracle yourself, put #define I_IMPORTED_TESTING_DLL before the #import

Comment: @HansPassant yes that's the backup plan.

Comment: You don't seem to grasp what #import does.  It is just a code-generator, nothing more.  It generates the testing.tlh and testing.tli files in the build directory.  Just have a look at them with your text editor to convince yourself which way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is achievable and here's why: DLLs are loaded in runtime while compiler macros are resolved at compile time, so, in my understanding, I don't think you can achieve this behaviour.

Comment: A `#import` does its work at compile time, it basically defines the function prototypes for all the entry points of the DLL.

Comment: So what kind of tests do you want to do exactly? You will only have the prototypes defined and not the actual implementation.

Comment: The implementation *is* the DLL which has already been compiled and linked.